# ODOO: Why is create_uid always 1?

Tags: default, odoo, odoo-10

Even when i'm adding and login as new users, the **create_uid** in the database is always **1**.

Can i change this default in ODOO?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen to you in all models?

Comment: @forvas Yes, in my model, i tried to get the current user using: 'current_user = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Current User', default=lambda self: self.env.user)' and it gives me 1 even when i'm using another user

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the model is created as superuser using sudo() method. First the non admin user have the proper access rights to create records in that model.

Answer (score 1):

Check how many users are there in this table 'rs_users'. also check which table  your getting it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in your code:
In python code, using `self.env.user.id`
While in xml code, using 'uid'